# Is there a way to link jquery to html without use of a cdn?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to link a jquery page to my HTML. Is there a way to do this without using a CDN or downloading from the jquery site?
I want it to be like linking a standard js file (like below).

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Host it on your own site?

Comment: Download it from the jQuery site. Upload it to your server. reference it

Comment: What do you mean by "without downloading from the jquery site?" exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want to use the latest version (3.6.0), one way to do this, would be to go to [jQuery official site](https://code.jquery.com/) and choose the version you want to use, then copy the src code link, like so:

[image]

Navigate to it, copy all the code and paste it into your **own js file** which you can name whatever way you would like.  And then you would be able to link jQuery like so: `<script src="MyJquery.js"></script>`

In the case of my example I'm using the format `min.js` , the minified version, so you would need to do it like so: `<script src="MyJquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: So by _all the code_, do you mean the part you highlighted in the screenshot or the entire code in the screenshot?

Comment: No no. Copy that link of the screenshot, NAVIGATE to that link and then copy all the code in the page of that link, which is the jQuery code you need.

Comment: So I put this in:
_https://code.jquery.com/jquey-3.6.0.min.js_ and it comes up with a 404

Comment: go to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js

Comment: So then do I paste the entire code into a js file?

Comment: yes but save it like so `myFile.min.js` where `myFile` can be any name that you want, and then link it like this `<script src="myFile.min.js"></script>`

Comment: So save as in ctrl + s, save it as myFile.min.js and then link that to the script, in which you write your jquery?